# Correct way to define a constant C-string in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, auto, cstring

Most of the time I see constant C-strings defined as:

```
static char const* MY_CONSTANT = "Hello World";
```

However, the *pointer itself* is not `const`. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to do it like below?

```
static char const* const MY_CONSTANT = "Hello World";
```

There are 2 goals with constant globals like this, I think:

1. Do not allow modification of the string
2. Do not allow the variable to point to anything else

I simply assumed these 2 goals were needed when defining constant strings.

Another interesting thing is that I am allowed to do this:

```
int main()
{
    auto MY_CONSTANT = "";
    MY_CONSTANT = "Another String";
}
```

This tells me that `auto` deduces the string as `char const*` and not `char const* const`.

So I have two main questions:

1. What is the most appropriate way to define constant c-style strings (I suppose constant pointers-to-something, is the more general question?). Why do you choose one or the other?
2. Concerning my example with `auto`, it makes sense why it chooses `char const*` (because it's the array of data that's constant, not the pointer itself). Could I make `auto` deduce to `char const* const` or can I change the code to make it result in such a type?

Comment: Don't you mean `const char* const`?

Comment: @Adam Both forms are valid C++. Yours does the same as mine.

Comment: the default that `auto` detects is the minimal restriction, which means that the fact that the variable cannot be reassigned is just your choice. you can do `auto const` I suppose, if you want, but its best not to impose it on everybody.

Comment: A string literal can be binded to a `const char *`; whether you wanna the string variable to be constant is up to you. You are asking the same question as `should I use const int i=0 or int i=0`

Comment: I think OP alludes to the fact that there's a lot of code out there that forgets to use top-level const when it was intended that the pointer would not be changed.   If you have to program on an embedded environment where this makes a difference to how much static data are you have available, you learn pretty quickly to put the extra `const` in!

Comment: Another variety you didn't mention is `char const s[] = "Hello, World!";` . (In C++ the keyword `static` is redundant because namespace-scope `const`s default to being static, although it is practical to use it anyway in case someone ports your header to C and doesn't realize this).

Comment: Neither `static char const* MY_CONSTANT = "Hello World";` nor `static char const* const MY_CONSTANT = "Hello World";` is more correct that the other. They mean different things. Use whichever one is more appropriate for your current needs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well if it a truly a constant then *constexpr* would be the C++11 way to do this:

```
constexpr char const* MY_CONSTANT = "Hello World";
```

The first example:

```
static char const* MY_CONSTANT = "Hello World";
```

just says I have a pointer to a char const that has static storage duration, which if it is outside of a function would make it a global.

If we required the pointer to also be const then we need the second form your introduced. It all depends on whether the pointer is indeed supposed to const or not. In most cases, the reason your see code without the top-level const is because they just forgot to put it in not because they did not mean the pointer to also be const.

Where *static* makes a difference for example if whether you want a *const* member to be per-instance or per-class:

```
class A
{
        char const* const const_per_instance = "Other Const String";
    public:
        constexpr static char const* const const_per_class = "Hello World" ;
};
```

If we require the const to be per-class then we need to use *static* otherwise not. The example changes slightly if you are not allowed to use *constexpr*:

```
class A
{
        char const* const const_per_instance = "Other Const String";
    public:
        static char const* const const_per_class  ;
};

char const* const A::const_per_class = "Hello World" ;
```

but the essence is the same just the syntax is different.

For your second question as [Gotw #92](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/07/gotw-92-solution-auto-variables-part-1/) says auto drops top level const, one example given is as follows:

```
const int   ci  = val;  
auto        g   = ci;
```

and it says:

> The type of g is int.
>
> Remember, just because ci is const (read-only) doesn’t have any
>   bearing on whether we want g to be const. It’s a separate variable. If
>   we wanted g to be const, we would have said const auto as we did in case c above

the example that is being referred to is as follows:

```
int         val = 0;  
//..
const auto  c   = val;
```

Comment: Sadly constexpr is not supported on msvc 12 :-(

Comment: @void.pointer you don't need *constexpr* the answer does not change just the syntax. I updated the answer to include an example without *constexpr* as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
constexpr auto& MY_CONSTANT = "Hello World";
```

- MY_CONSTANT has type `const char (&)[12]`
- No decay (the array bound isn't lost)
- Everything is constant - the array itself and the reference (by definition)
- Everything is constexpr (can be used at compile time) - the array itself and the reference
- MY_CONSTANT has internal linkage due to `constexpr` and can be used in headers

Comment: With VC++ `static auto& MY_CONSTANT = "Hello World";` can be used instead.

Comment: `static` has nothing to do with constancy. It means that function is not visible in other compilation units.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `constexpr` doesn't change linkage, so you'll still need `static` ?

Comment: @golvok `const`s have internal linkage by default.

Answer (score 0):

It's a rare case where it happens that you do overwrite your pointer which points to a const value, therefore most developers omit the second const but **semantically** it would be indeed correct this way:

```
static char const* const MY_CONSTANT = "Hello World";
```

or in this form:

```
static const char* const MY_CONSTANT = "Hello World";
```

constexpr for the declaration is just needed if it is part of another constexpr function like this:

```
static constexpr const char* const MY_CONSTANT = "Hello World";
static constexpr const char* Foo()
{
    // ...
    return MY_CONSTANT;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well done for noticing the const on the pointer part! Many people don't realise that bit.

To prevent the string literal from being duplicated per translation unit (or make it easier for the string-pooling part of the optimizer), I suggest putting the actual data in a source file somewhere. This will also save some recompiling if you change the text.

header:

`extern const char *const mystring;`

source:

`extern const char *const mystring = "hello";`

Alternatively

header:

`extern const std::string mystring;`

source:

`extern std::string mystring = "hello";`